# pow function different output for cout and printf?

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf, cout

I was writing a program to calculate negative powers of 2. 
I used the following two code snippets:

```
cout.precision(3);
cout << scientific << pow(2.0, p) << endl;
```

AND

```
ans = pow(2.0, p);
printf("%.3e\n", ans);
```

For `p = -8271`, the `cout` gives the right answer (1.517e-2490) but I get a widely different answer for the `printf` (6.929e-310). Why does this discrepancy occur?

I use Codeblocks on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can we see the variable declaration for `ans`?  If it isn't of type `double`, then you might be passing the wrong type of argument to `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that's because `ans` is a `long double`, but you didn't tell `printf` to expect a `long double`. The format code you want is `%.3Le` assuming that's the case.

The g++ compiler even has a warning to detect format/parameter mismatches (I think it comes with `-Wall`) but I always prefer iostreams because they're type safe like this.

All this is of course assuming that `p` is also `long double`, causing the compiler to pick the `long double` version of `pow`.

Comment: ans is a long double. Mark B, you are right! I changed the parameter to %.3Le and now it works beautifully. Thanks a tonne for the help.